# Not enough storage error when trying to update an app

Tags: nexus-4, insufficient-memory, application-autoupdate

I have a Nexus 4 with more than 500 MB free storage space:

[image: 507 MB available]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Now I would like to update Chrome, but I get the error, that there is not enough free space to update it:

[image: Not enough storage for Chrome]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

I would say this is bug. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I also find it weird. Having free spaces 20 times the size of an app is still not enough to download and install it. What I do is manually move some of the App's data folders in internal storage (Android/data and Android/obb), to external SD card (usually huge games that are taking lot of space), and move them internal storage only when I want to play them. Move them back later.

Not to mention other methods such as clearing your cache, uninstalling unnecessary apps, moving apps to sd card (if available).

Comment: Good method. However a set back comes into play regarding less techie users. This issue needs to be highly addressed.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give this a try:
[How to fix insufficient storage issue](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/google-android/3498845/how-fix-androids-insufficient-storage-available-error-message/)

Comment: First I did it already and second: I do not understand why I should delete anything, if there are more than 500 MB of free space.

Comment: the app you are downloading might be 50 MB, but sometimes the app downloads its own data via network, which could be multiple MB/GBs.